# Find text with like

Tags: mysql

I want to find text in a MySql database

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM blog
                             WHERE text_post LIKE = 't%';
                            ")
or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {
    echo $row['titol_post'] . "<br>";
}
```

It gives me the error:
mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given...

If I substitute

```
WHERE text_post LIKE = 't%';
```

by

```
WHERE text_post = 'test';
```

It works well. I do not undestand. Why the LIKE does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed `like =` to `like` and it works

`SELECT * FROM blog WHERE text_post LIKE 't%'"`

Answer (score 2):

Here like after = is probelm please replace

with

```
WHERE text_post LIKE = 't%';
```

to

```
WHERE text_post LIKE 't%';
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_error()`, like all other `mysqli_xx()` functions, requires that you pass the connection variable to it, so that it knows which DB connection you want to know the last error for.

```
...
or die(mysqli_error($con));
...
```

Once you've done this, you will get a more useful error message that will help you diagnose the problem with your SQL code.

When you do get the real SQL error message, you will find that the problem is with the `=` sign.

The reason for this is that `LIKE` is an operator in the same way as `=`. You can only use one operator here, so if you're using `LIKE`, then you don't need `=` as well.

Your SQL code would therefore change to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM blog
WHERE text_post LIKE 't%
```

Comment: I did not know that. Very useful

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass conn in the error function:

```
or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

The [MySQL syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.error.html) says:

> string mysqli_error(mysqli link);
>
> Returns the last error message for the most recent MySQLi function
>   call that can succeed or fail.

Also you need to remove the = sign after the LIKE keyword

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM blog
                             WHERE text_post LIKE  't%';
                            ")
or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to write sql query in mysql. Please replace your query with this.

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM blog
                             WHERE text_post LIKE 't%';
                            ")